# How do I get the comment of a specific column with Doctrine ORM

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

Is there a way to retrieve the column's comment (like from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN table on MySQL) from a certain table without actually "hardcode" the query with Doctrine ORM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found an way. what I was trying to do was get a column comment from inside a Controller

```
//lets say we have a table named 'product'
//and we want to get the comment from the 'name' column
//first we get a list of columns from 'product'
$columns = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->getSchemaManager()->listTableColumns('product');
//then we just access getComment function from the 'Column' class
//for the 'name' column:
echo $columns['name']->getComment();
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it, and the same would go for Propel as well. Both use PDO, and afaik there is no database-neutral way to do this.

To achieve this, you can often query the table columns using SELECT statements on system tables (certainly Oracle and PostgreSQL allow this). However, the names of the tables involved differ from one vendor to another. [Here](http://bytes.com/topic/postgresql/answers/692471-how-get-column-names-table) is how to get column names, for example, in PostgreSQL - getting comments would probably be quite similar.

It would be quite possible for an ORM to offer what you want, but the underlying implementation would be the approach I outline above. Perhaps you could request it on the Doctrine mailing list?

Comment: First thanks for your effort. Well, internally the ORM heart is the "Information Schema" of the many database that they abstract, as you stated above as "system tables" from Oracle and PostgreSQL. For example, when ORM reverse engineer your base to create the mapping (like Propel does) they get the column names, foreign keys, table names, etc. from Information Schema, and I know you also can get a Column Comment from there. The question is, how Doctrine do it

Comment: Ah, good point. A quick browse of the DBAL source brings up [line 284 here](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/PostgreSqlSchemaManager.php) - and lo and behold, includes a lookup for column comments. Great!